# Making a conditional statement to send email alert

Tags: php, mysql, email, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a conditional statement to stop an email alert when the fail.php is called.  Right now I'm getting an email alert for both good and fail results.

I do not want to receive an email if the the result failed.  Should I make two scripts or is there a way t make this work together?

Thanks

Here is the section I'm referring to along with the whole script.

```
if (mysql_affected_rows($result) > 0) {
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);  
$reg =          $_REQUEST['reg'] ; 
$first_name =   $_REQUEST['first_name']; 
header("location: reg_add_success.php?reg=" . urlencode($reg) . "&first_name=" . urlencode($first_name)); 
} 
else { 
header("location: reg_add_fail.php"); 
exit(); // as sugested by John Conde
}
```

---

```
<?

$to = 'newreg@41q.org';
$subject = 'New Homeless Connection';
$msg = "<html>
<head>
<title>New Homeless Connection</title>
</head>

<body>
<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"10\" border=\"1\" align=\"left\">
<tr>
<td align=\"left\" width=\"150px\">Registery No.:</td>
<td align=\"left\"> $reg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=\"left\">First Name:</td>
<td align=\"left\">$first_name </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=\"left\">Connection Date:</td>
<td align=\"left\"$>$connect_date</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td align=\"left\" colspan=\"2\">http://www.41q.org/admin/</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
";

// Make sure to escape quotes

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Homeless' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$submit_date = date("m/d/y g:i A") ; 

$order = "INSERT INTO reg_add (submit_date, 
connect_date, 
reg, 
first_name, 
)

VALUES

('$submit_date',
'$_POST[connect_date]', 
'{$_POST[reg]}nv', 
'$_POST[first_name]')";

$result = mysql_query($order);

if (mysql_affected_rows($result) > 0) {
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);  
$reg =          $_REQUEST['reg'] ; 
$first_name =   $_REQUEST['first_name']; 
header("location: reg_add_success.php?reg=" . urlencode($reg) . "&first_name=" . urlencode($first_name)); 
} 
else { 
header("location: reg_add_fail.php"); 
exit(); // as sugested by John Conde
}
?>
```

Comment: instead of `if ($result)`, use `if( mysql_query($order) )`

Comment: Could you be a little more clear on what you want? You don't want an email if the values aren't inserted into the database? Do you not want to have a success and fail page, but just one page?

Comment: Are you getting two mails on success?

Comment: To answer your question, I am getting two emails of success whether it fails or not.

Comment: I'm trying to stop the email if the script directs me to the fail page (no need to have an email sent if there is  fail).  I only want emails if success.

Comment: Erik i have posted the entire code kindly test that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your code

```
// Make sure to escape quotes

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; $headers .= 'From: Homeless' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

This code is already sending the mail regard less of the result.

You just need to remove this line from top code

```
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

and your code will work fine.

Comment: I can't eliminate the header.

Comment: You had that line two times in your code. This first line is sending the mail regardless of the result either it is true or false

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first instance of `mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);`.

Then, for good measure, check the number of rows affected, rather than true/false (although both should work).

```
if (mysql_affected_rows($result) > 0) {

}
```

Comment: The query is inserting into the database.  The result is either `true` or `false`. So his if statement is correct. **EDIT** Much better.

Comment: Just saw the whole code. Could have sworn it wasn't there when I wrote the answer. My answer has been updated.

Comment: +1 from me. Good to see an answer not to check if $result returned true, but instead seeing if any rows were affected.

Comment: Is it me, or are there 2 mail's being sent regardless - right before setting the timezone, and also conditionally on $result?

Comment: Ha, yes Greg. Admittedly, I didn't take the time to look at every line of his code.

Answer (score 0):

Final code, kindly test ite

```
<?

$to = 'newreg@41q.org';
$subject = 'New Homeless Connection';
$msg = "<html>
<head>
<title>New Homeless Connection</title>
</head>

<body>
<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"10\" border=\"1\" align=\"left\">
<tr>
<td align=\"left\" width=\"150px\">Registery No.:</td>
<td align=\"left\"> $reg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=\"left\">First Name:</td>
<td align=\"left\">$first_name </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=\"left\">Connection Date:</td>
<td align=\"left\"$>$connect_date</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td align=\"left\" colspan=\"2\">http://www.41q.org/admin/</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
";

// Make sure to escape quotes

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Homeless' . "\r\n";

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$submit_date = date("m/d/y g:i A") ; 

$order = "INSERT INTO reg_add (submit_date, 
connect_date, 
reg, 
first_name, 
)

VALUES

('$submit_date',
'$_POST[connect_date]', 
'{$_POST[reg]}nv', 
'$_POST[first_name]')";

$result = mysql_query($order);

if (mysql_affected_rows($result) > 0) {
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);  
$reg =          $_REQUEST['reg'] ; 
$first_name =   $_REQUEST['first_name']; 
header("location: reg_add_success.php?reg=" . urlencode($reg) . "&first_name=" . urlencode($first_name)); 
} 
else { 
header("location: reg_add_fail.php"); 
exit(); // as sugested by John Conde
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I currently see some sql injections plus invalid query `first_name,` extra `,` at the end, constants used in posts array keys, a mix of request and post, large html block of code and no checks on validity of the values passed.

If you check for valid values then you can determine if the script should continue to the mail and update the database parts:

**Heres a clean up of your code hope it helps:**

```
<?php 

$to = 'newreg@41q.org';
$subject = 'New Homeless Connection';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    if(isset($_POST['first_name']) && strlen($_POST['first_name'])>1){
        $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['reg']) && strlen($_POST['reg'])>1){
        $reg=$_POST['reg'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['connect_date']) && strlen($_POST['connect_date'])>1){
        $connect_date=$_POST['connect_date'];
    }

    if(!isset($first_name) || !isset($reg) || !isset($connect_date)){
        header("location: reg_add_fail.php");
        exit();
    }
}else{
//the page the post from
header("location: reg_form.php");
exit();
}

$msg=<<<EMAIL
<html>
<head>
<title>New Homeless Connection</title>
</head>

<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="1" align="left">
<tr>
<td align="left" width="150px">Registery No.:</td>
<td align="left">$reg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">First Name:</td>
<td align="left">$first_name </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">Connection Date:</td>
<td align="left">$connect_date</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td align="left" colspan="2">http://www.41q.org/admin/</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
EMAIL;

// Make sure to escape quotes
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Homeless' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$submit_date = date("m/d/y g:i A") ;

$order = "INSERT INTO reg_add (submit_date,connect_date, reg, first_name)
          VALUES ('{$submit_date}',".mysql_real_escape_string($connect_date)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($reg)."nv','".mysql_real_escape_string($first_name)."')";

$result = mysql_query($order);

header("Location: ./reg_add_success.php?reg=".urlencode($reg)."&first_name=".urlencode($first_name));
die;
?>
```